# Find the point on the parabola y^2 = 2x + 3 that is closest to a point (x, y).

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations, conic-sections, education

Iv tried as below and end up with a wierd expression and the only way to solve it is to use a computer software is there any other method to find the x and y coordinates.

Comment: It's more likely you'll get good answers if you type out the equations in MathJax. Currently, the handwriting is tricky to read.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.

Comment: @kingW3 Notice that this user tried to do the same thing to another question, after an answer was obtained.  This establishes a pattern of suspicious behavior that is not only in violation of community guidelines, but suggests attempts at cheating.

Comment: @heropup Eh I see :( I'll flag this post.

Comment: Do not vandalize the post. You (or anyone else) is welcom to TeXify it, because photos of notebook pages are also frowned upon. Also deleting the post after getting an answer is against the site rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed in the following manner 
1. Shift the orgin to (-3/2,0)
2. Assume parametric coordinates for the parabola. 
3. Write the distance using distance formula( from the given pt)
4. Minimise using differentiation

Comparitively lesser calculations....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: is this the right solution though?

Comment: Find the normal to the curve passing through the point $(-4,7)$. The point where it cuts the curve will be the closest point.